# Rails generate isn't working in the development of a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-generators

I'm building a small Gem at the moment, and I'd like to be able to use Rails G for certain things, but every time I do, I get the same (long) response

I thought it was possible to use Rails G despite not actually working in the rails environment when building a gem?

Here's the response:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /Users/David/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/postgresql/sqlite3/oracle/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
      [--webpack=WEBPACK]                                # Preconfigure for app-like JavaScript with Webpack (options: react/vue/angular)
      [--skip-yarn], [--no-skip-yarn]                    # Don't use Yarn for managing JavaScript dependencies
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]  # Skip Action Mailer files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -P, [--skip-puma], [--no-skip-puma]                    # Skip Puma related files
  -C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]    # Skip Action Cable files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
      [--skip-listen], [--no-skip-listen]                # Don't generate configuration that depends on the listen gem
      [--skip-coffee], [--no-skip-coffee]                # Don't use CoffeeScript
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                    # Skip test files
      [--skip-system-test], [--no-skip-system-test]      # Skip system test files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--api], [--no-api]                                # Preconfigure smaller stack for API only apps
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
```

Answer (score 1):

set separate .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset file

install rails gem and bundler gem.

You can use the generators which are available for non rails app.

Comment: The question is about running generators in a non-rails folder, not about updating the rails bin.

Comment: Sorry. Add that as a note in your question. By default generally 
we assume it is in rails folder.
Also I have experience In facing these issue. Updating the bin makes the generator to work properly

Comment: I'm not asking any questions

Comment: Hmm, it's an interesting edit, have you used that actually? Had never thought about doing it like this.